# Javascript Play/Pause button Keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm still working on a music player, mouse controls have been assigned, but I'm having little trouble with keyboard events on the PLAY/PAUSE button.

So far, I got the user to be able to "click" the PLAY button by pressing SPACEBAR. What happens is that the PLAY button is being hidden and replaced by the PAUSE button.

Which I want now is getting the user to be able to press the SPACEBAR again so it "clicks" PAUSE, and therefore shows PLAY again.

Here is what I have :

html

```
<div>

            <a href="#" id="play"> </a> 

            <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;"></a>

</div>
```

script

```
<script>

/* mouse */

    $('#play').on('click', function(event) {
        console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();

    $('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();

    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    });

/* keyboard */

var play = document.getElementById("play");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");


document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        play.click();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
        pause.click();
    }
}; 


    </script>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I can't find closing curly bracket of first line function, check that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first mistake is that you arent closing all brackets,the second  is this part of code:

```
if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    play.click();
}
else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    pause.click();
}
```

i suggest to use a variable for check if the button play is being pressed or not:

```
 var ispaused = true;
 var play = document.getElementById("play");
var pause = document.getElementById("pause");
 $('#play').on('click', function(event) {
 ispaused = false;
        console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();

    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();

/* keyboard */




});
    $('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    ispaused = true;
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();

    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    });

    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    if(ispaused == true ){
        play.click();
        }else{
        pause.click();
        }
    }

};
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owurauur/)

Answer (score 1):

the mistake is here:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    play.click();
  } else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    pause.click();
  }
};
```

the second condition cannot be executed because everytime the keyCode is 32 it's goes only in the first conditions.
You can declare a variable "isPlaying" that indicate you if the player is playing.

```
var isPlaying = false;
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 32) {
  if (isPlaying) {
    pause.click();
  } else {
    play.click();
  }
  isPlaying = !isPlaying; // if true equal false, if false equal true
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. you double check space keyCode when you space anytime and the first condition would be true every single time.

Second, you need to use $bla instead for $("#blablabla") .It runs almost 600 line Code with find object you select everytime.So don't be let duplicate work.

Final,$() is lik $(doucument).ready().It's all done when rendered it's done and DOM it's OK.THAT IS!

** code **

```
$(function () {
  let $play = $("#play");
  let $pause = $("#pause");
  $play.on('click', function (event) {
    console.log('play click clicked');
    //currentPlayingTrack.play();
    $pause.show();
    $play.hide();
  });
  $pause.on('click', function (event) {
    //currentPlayingTrack.pause();
    $pause.hide();
    $play.show();
  });

  /* keyboard */

  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      toggle = !toggle;
      $play.trigger("click");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      toggle = !toggle;
      $pause.trigger("click");
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing a bit more knowledge of js which will come with time :) Here's a codepen on how I'd accomplish this.

http://codepen.io/smplejohn/pen/zNVbRb

```
<a href="#" class="playpause">Play</a> 
<a href="#" class="playpause" style="display:none">Pause</a>

$('.playpause').click(function(){
  $('.playpause').toggle();
  return false;
});

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32){     
    $('.playpause').toggle();
  }
};
```